# Targeting test NetBeans deployment to a WebLogic cluster

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, weblogic

I develop a J2EE application using NetBeans 8.0.2 connected to a local WebLogic 10.3.6.0 installation. The project is Ant based.

[The WebLogic plugin for NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf-jpa-weblogic.html#01b) (at least, its UI) offers to select a WebLogic domain for test deployment, but not a server/cluster inside it. In practice, the deployment goes to the domain's AdminServer.

But the AdminServer is always standalone and, therefore, unsuitable for testing cluster specific features. For instance, an application with a [`<singleton-service>`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13706/app_xml.htm#WLPRG473) in its weblogic-application.xml is absolutely unable to be run on a standalone server.

So, I ask: is there some way to setup NetBeans to target the test deployment to a user defined cluster instead of the AdminServer?

Please don't mention the option of building EAR files and then deploying them with WLST or manually: I look for the way to get the standard "Deploy" menu item working as needed.

Comment: Check the deployment/remote deployment section here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/soa/eisele-weblogic-netbeans-2193786.html You should be able to set the deployment targets

Comment: Thank you, but I looked for a local deployment with Ant, not the remote one with Maven.

Comment: It works with Eclipse IDE if you can afford it, but indeed I could not see the option inside the NetBeans IDE.